# Is this poem about frogs from Non Non Biyori Repeat a common poem/rhyme?

Tags: japanese-language, non-non-biyori

In *Non Non Biyori Repeat* episode 4, Ren-chan sings this poem/rhyme which goes (translated/subtitled version)

> Frogs Frogs
>   Frogs are grown-ups, Tadpoles are children
>   When they grow hind legs they are moochers
>   When they grow front legs they are rebellious

Is this a Japanese nursery rhyme or something the showrunners/mangaka created themselves?

Comment: The same lyrics was in Non Non Biyori Chapter 57, so we know for sure it's not something exclusive to the anime. I'm not sure whether it's Japanese nursery rhyme or not, but I doubt so, since I couldn't find the same lyrics posted anywhere before 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ren-chan's "Frog's Song" is either a parody or otherwise an original song.**

As [nhahtdh commented](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46669/is-this-poem-from-non-non-biyori-repeat-a-common-poem-rhyme#comment60818_46669), the song lyric couldn't be found outside of *Non Non Biyori*-related results, making it an original song. The song is also known to the fans as れんちょんのかえるのうた (*Ren-chon no kaeru no uta*, Ren-chon's "Frog's Song"). It can be listened on [Nico Nico Douga, starting at 0:45](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm26819439).

> かえる かえる
>   かえるはおとな
>   おたまはこども
>   うしろあしはえたらすねかじり
>   まえあしはえたらはんこうき
>
> Frogs Frogs
>   Frogs are grown-ups
>   Tadpoles are children
>   When they grow hind legs they are moochers
>   When they grow front legs they are rebellious

On the other hand, there is also a Japanese nursery rhyme called かえるのうた (*kaeru no uta*, Frog's Song), also known as かえるのがっしょう (*kaeru no gasshou*, Frog's Choir). The song can be listened on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXBLU7g4elQ). However, the melody and the lyric are different.

> かえるのうたが
>   きこえてくるよ
>   クヮ クヮ クヮ クヮ
>   ケケケケ ケケケケ
>   クヮクヮクヮ
>
> The frog's song
>   We can hear it
>   Ribbit ribbit ribbit ribbit
>   Ribbit-ribbit-ribbit-ribbit ribbit-ribbit-ribbit-ribbit
>   Ribbit ribbit  ribbit

Lastly, there are other songs ([collected on Nico Nico Douga](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm26804395)) Ren-chan has sung on the anime regarding [rabbits, little birds, and **dynamites**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDJ1igUsPjE), [*nekojyarashi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setaria_viridis) (cat toys), paint it black, [**a fake doctor** and **a ripped love letter**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZBvQIe3JQA), and a diary. Considering the nonsensical lyric and sometimes heavy topics, all of these don't seem to be taken from existing Japanese nursery rhymes; parodies at best, or else original songs.

Considering all of these, Ren-chan's "Frog's Song" is either a parody of a famous Japanese nursery rhyme with the same name or otherwise just an original song.